# Firebase UI in Chrome extension: signInSuccess never called

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

It drives me mad, so posting it here after 3 wasted days of applying "drop-in" auth solution. Hopefully, anyone can shed any light on what I'm missing.

Basically I've setup faribes app in the dashboard and successfully inited farebase in my chrome extension. When I drop firebasUI for email/password authentication, it seems to work fine - it successfully checks if email exists or not and shows the respective flow. For signup, it creates a user in firebase database once the flow is completed.

The problem is that signInSuccess is never called neither in signin nor in signup flow.
Moreover `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` always returns `null` user

If I use plain `signInWithEmailAndPassword() / createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` everything works fine and `onAuthStateChanged()` returns the correct user.

Below is the code I'm using in the chrome extension:

**credentials.js (popup script):**

```
//init firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "<my_key>",
    authDomain: "<my_domain>",
    databaseURL: "<my_dburl>",
    projectId: "<my_projectid>",
    storageBucket: "<my_storagebucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<my_id>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


//ui config for firebaseUI
var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: 'http://google.com',
    credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
            console.log('sign in success');
            console.log(currentUser);
            // alert(currentUser)
            return false;
        },
        uiShown: function () {
            console.log("uiShow");
        }
    },
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInOptions: [{
        provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        requireDisplayName: false
    }]
};

//launch the firebaseUI flow
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

**credentials.html (popup html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.css" />
  <script src="credentials.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
     Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
<h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Some Name",
  "description": "Some description",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "credentials.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "https://*/*",
    "activeTab",
    "background"
  ],

  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com https://apis.google.com https://www.googleapis.com https://securetoken.googleapis.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://cdn.firebase.com https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",

  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<numbers.letters.apps.googleusercontent.com>",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ]
  },
  "key":"<my_chrome_extension_key>"
}
```

Note: seems like I can put any `client_id` and it doesn't make any difference (`firebaseUI` doesn't work and `firebase` works anyway)

I was following [this github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension) steps and used the code base from the repo

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's appeared it's a bug in firebaseUI:

Instead of using this link:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
```

I'm now using this one:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/2.5.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
```

Now it works - thanks to [bojeil-google](https://github.com/bojeil-google) for the support!